# How to update a table row, given the RowID and the Value to update. MVC C# Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, paypal

Here is my code. PayPal sends the ActionResult the RowID which is `item_number` and the transaction id which is `pp_txn_id`. I simple want to reference the row in my transaction table, `tblPayPalTransactions`, and update it with the `pp_txn_id` which I see is sent back to me after purchase in PayPal. Then photo links are sent to `DownloadPicture.cshtml` view.

I simply can't figure the syntax out to update the transaction table. Everything else I can do. Stuck here trying to finish a project.

```
//ROW IN PHOTOS IS item_number, PAYPAL PAID TRANSACTION IS pp_txn_id
public ActionResult thankyou(string item_number, string pp_txn_id)
{

    var photo = db.PayPalTransactions.Where(x => x.RowID == Convert.ToInt32(item_number));
    photo.pp_txn_id = pp_txn_id;
    db.SubmitChanges();

    var thisPaidPhoto = (from p in db.Photos
                         where p.PhotoId == Convert.ToInt32(item_number)
                         select p).FirstOrDefault();

    return View(thisPaidPhoto);
}
```

Comment: Not related but your parameter should be `int item_number` (and `Where(x => x.RowID == item_number)` if its an `int`

Comment: you should try parse or try catch the item number if it is null or empty or invalid value, just in case

Comment: Stephen Muecke, the number comes back in a querystring name/value pair and I'm pretty sure it is a string.

Comment: Yes, but if it can be converted to an `int`, then make the parameter `int item_number` - let the `DefaultModelBinder` do its magic. And if the value could not be converted to an int, then having `Convert.ToInt32(item_number)` would make no sense anyway (and everything sent from a browser is just text :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code will have compilation errors because the `Where` method returns a collection. So basically `photo` variable will be a collection type and it will not have a `pp_txn_id` property.

Assuming rowid is a unique identifier of the record in that table, you need to get a single record.

You may use `FirstOrDefault` method.

```
var rowId=Convert.ToInt32(item_number)
var photo = db.PayPalTransactions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RowID ==rowId);
if(photo!=null)
{
   // update now
   photo.pp_txn_id = pp_txn_id;
   db.SubmitChanges();
}
else
{
  // item does not exist in table. Handle as needed.
}
```

Also keep in mind that, the `Convert.ToInt32` method will throw an exception if the input is not a valid numeric value. I would use `Int32.TryParse` to be safe. but If you are sure the values are always going to be numeric type, i would recommend you to use a numeric type as param (`int` or `long`).

Comment: Yup! Thank you very much. I was using Where, which works for sending to a View, but not for updating single row. If it was a snake it would have bit me. Also, I used "SaveChanges()" instead of "SubmitChanges". Method didn't exist for Submit. No worries. The params coming back are basically the simplest form of PayPal interaction. Definitley hackable, not like PDT or IPN that uses POST values. But I am more interested in getting simple transaction ID back for a very inexpensive charge. But since they are in the querystring, they are text always.

Comment: I just want to say thank you very much. Quick response, solved my problem, allowing me to spend more time on learning how to surf and dance reggae. serious

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult thankyou(string item_number, string pp_txn_id)
{

    var photo = db.PayPalTransactions.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RowID == Convert.ToInt32(item_number));
    if(photo != null){
        photo.pp_txn_id = pp_txn_id;
        db.SubmitChanges();


        var thisPaidPhoto = (from p in db.Photos
                             where p.PhotoId == Convert.ToInt32(item_number)
                             select p).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(thisPaidPhoto);
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```